# SQL select grouping and subtract

Tags: sql

i have table named source table with data like this :
[image]

And i want to do query that subtract row with status plus and minus to be like this group by product name :

[image]

How to do that in SQL query? thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `CASE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the product and then use a conditional SUM()

```
select product, 
       sum(case when status = 'plus' then total else 0 end) - 
       sum(case when status = 'minus' then total else 0 end) as total,
       sum(case when status = 'plus' then amount else 0 end) - 
       sum(case when status = 'minus' then amount else 0 end) as amount 
from your_table
group by product
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another method using `join`, which works for the particular data you have provided (which has one "plus" and one "minus" row per product):

```
select tplus.product, (tplus.total - tminus.total) as total,
       (tplus.amount - tminus.amount) as amount
from t tplus join
     t tminus
     on tplus.product = tminus.product and
        tplus.status = 'plus' and
        tplus.status = 'minus';
```

Both this and the aggregation query work well for the data you have provided.  In other words, there are multiple ways to solve this problem (each has its strengths).

Answer (score 1):

you can query as below:

```
select product , sum (case when [status] = 'minus' then -Total else Total end) as Total
    , sum (case when [status] = 'minus' then -Amount else Amount end) as SumAmount
from yourproduct
    group by product
```